# dojox calendar don't show events

Tags: dojo, calendar

I'm trying to work with dojox.Calendar to show events but it doesn't work

The calendar widget is populated with a list of data items using a store set on its store property.
Here is the dojox.Calendar code

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojox/calendar/themes/claro/Calendar.css">
        <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: false,isDebug: true}</script>
        <script src='dojo/dojo.js'></script>

        <script>
            require([
            "dojox/calendar/Calendar",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/_base/Deferred",
            "dijit/_base/manager",      
            "dojo/domReady!"
            ],
            function(Calendar,Memory,Deferred,manager,Observable) {
                var mem = new Memory({data:{    
                                "id":"1",
                                "summary":"Daily Call",
                                "startTime": new Date(2014, 0, 1, 10, 0),
                                "endTime": new Date(2014, 0, 1, 14, 0),

                               }
                        });
                console.log("mem is --->  "+JSON.stringify(mem));   
                calendar = new Calendar({
                        dateInterval:"month",
                        startTimeAttr: "startTime",
                        endTimeAttr: "endTime"  

                    },"calDiv");    

                store: new Observable(new Memory({data: someData})),

                calendar.startup(); 
                console.log("store"+JSON.stringify(calendar.get("store")));
            }

            );  
       </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
      <div id="calDiv"> </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

any help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things

1. The store assignment should be within the new Calendar constructor
2. The data object should be an array
3. You have to import the Observable Class

   ```
    require([
   "dojox/calendar/Calendar",
   "dojo/store/Memory",
   "dojo/_base/Deferred",
   "dijit/_base/manager",
   "dojo/store/Observable"
   "dojo/domReady!"],

   function (Calendar, Memory, Deferred, manager, Observable) {
   mem = new Memory({
       data: [{
           "id": 1,
               "summary": "Daily Call",
               "startTime": new Date(2014, 2, 25, 9, 0),
               "endTime": new Date(2014, 2, 25, 11, 0)
       }]
   });
   console.log("mem is --->  " + JSON.stringify(mem));
   var calendar = new Calendar({
       dateInterval: "month",
       startTimeAttr: "startTime",
       endTimeAttr: "endTime",
       store: new Observable(mem)
   }, "calDiv");


   calendar.startup();
   }

   );
   ```

   Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/ULX2w/